# GET http:/// HTTP/1.1 - Curl doesn't extract GET request

Tags: python, sockets, curl, http-get

I wrote a simple proxyserver code that connects to a client (currently the local machine) and retrieves data from a server (again running on the local machine) through HTTP GET requests that I incorporate into the curl command

Here's the curl command

```
curl -x http://localhost:12345 ​ http://127.0.0.1:20000/1.txt
```

But despite making the connection, the curl command doesn't seem to extract the GET request. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the code I've written as it seems to work on other PCs, it just won't work on mine

Here's the data I received from the socket that is supposed to contain the GET request

```
listening to host:  ('127.0.0.1', 58274)
GET http:/// HTTP/1.1
Host: 
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And here's a snippet of the code I used to just make the the connection through the socket

```
import socket, sys, os
from thread import *
import operator

try:
    listening_port = 12345
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nUser Requested an interrupt"
    print "Application Exiting ..."
    sys.exit()

max_conn = 5
buffer_size = 40960
def main():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('',listening_port))
        s.listen(max_conn)
    except Exception, e:
        print "\nUnable to initialize socket"
        sys.exit(2)
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print "Connection with client established"
            print "listening to host: ", addr
            print conn.recv(1024)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "\nProxy Server shutting down ..."
            sys.exit(1)
    s.close()
```

Does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening ? I'm new to sockets and networking in general, I'd really appreciate it if I could get some help.

Thanks